# Change markdown emphasis notation in pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

Is it possible to modify the character used to denote start/end of *emphasis* and **strong emphasis** in `pandoc`'s markdown?

In particular, I'd like to use *`/emphasis/`* and **`*strong emphasis*`**.

Comment: N.B. - this would seem a better fit for unix.SE, but [tag:pandoc] here has 918 questions, compared to only 5 over there. So I assume it's okay (or better) to ask here.

Comment: There is no easy way, because /emph/ is not recognized as special input. If it was just changing a type from A to B (e.g. strong emph to emph) that would be trivial with filters, but for this you would have to maybe hack into Pandoc itself with some Haskell

Comment: @SergioCorreia Thanks, that doesn't sound worth it...

Comment: there is no pandoc option to do this. You could use a preprocessor like [filepp](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~dm26/filepp/) to 1. replace every `*` at a word boundary with `__` or `**` and then 2. replace every `/` at a word boundary with `*` or `_`. Finally: `filepp myfile.md | pandoc -o myfile.html`

Comment: Thanks @scoa, that sounds like the way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option in pandoc to customize individual pieces of markdown syntax -- you would have to write another input format for that. I think the easiest way to achieve this is to use a pre-processor that converts your custom syntax into regular `markdown-strict` or `markdown` syntax.

Here is one example, using [filepp](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~dm26/filepp/) (there are many other options, including a sed or awk script):

```
#regexp /\/\b/_/
#regexp /\b\//_/
#regexp /\*\b/\*\*/
#regexp /\b\*/\*\*/

Some *bold* and some /emphasis/
```

To add the preprocessing step to compilation:

```
filepp -m regexp.pm myfile.md | pandoc ...
```

For instance, compiling to `pandoc -t html`:

```
<p>Some <strong>bold</strong> and some <em>emphasis</em></p>
```

To make this durable save the preproc commands in their own file, let's say `~/.pandoc-pp`

```
#regexp /\/\b/_/
#regexp /\b\//_/
#regexp /\*\b/\*\*/
#regexp /\b\*/\*\*/
```

And include at the top of every markdown document:

```
#include ~/.pandoc-pp
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it with sed, but I like the idea of having it in a file like that, much cleaner. And of course, I can avoid the need to include your last line in every file by changing the pipeline to: `echo '#include ~/.pandoc-pp' | cat - myfile.md | filepp -m regexp.pm | pandoc ...` :)

Answer (score 2):

`/emphasis/` is not markdown for emphasis, only `*foo*` and `_bar_` is... and the pandoc markdown writer currently only supports the former.

Either way, if you're asking about generating markdown; you could write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) that replaces `Emph x` with `Str "/" <> x <> Str "/")`. If you're asking about taking markdown as input to pandoc, you should probably try a preprocessor as suggested by @scoa.

Comment: 'Markdown' means so many different things that I think it would be fairer to say "is not a markdown we're aware of anyone using". Filtering looks like the right sort of thing though - but doesn't that happen too late? If the AST is already constructed when I filter, then at best *both* `*` & `/` will start emphasis?

Comment: @OllieFord well, your question is about pandoc markdown, so 'markdown', here, is not ambiguous: /emphasis/ is not (pandoc) markdown for emphasis.

Comment: @scoa I'm actually using `markdown_strict`, of which `markdown` (Pandoc's) is a superset. Didn't think it was important for the question - since I've already checked there isn't a Pandoc extension that changes the syntax (e.g. similar to `backtick_code_blocks`).